# Simple Proof by Induction: Question About Formulation of the Inductive Step.

Tags: induction, solution-verification

Prove $n^2 > n+1, n\geq2$:

**Basis**: n = 2

$n^2 > n+1$

$2^2 > 2+1$

$4>3$

**Inductive Hypothesis**: Assume P(k) is true, i.e.,

$k^2 > k+1$

**Inductive Step**: Show P(k+1) is true, i.e.,

$(k+1)^2 > (k+1) + 1$

$k^2 + 2k + 1 > (k+1) + 1$

$k^2 + 2k + 1 > k + 2$

$k^2 + 2k > k+1$

$k(k+2) > k + 1$

I know that I need to try and get the expression to read $k^2 > k+1$. The steps above are the closest I could get. Can some explain if my format for inductive proofs is correct and point me in the right direction to completing the proof?

Comment: You know that $k^2-k-1>0$. So, $k^2+k-1>0$, since $k>0$. And, adding $k+1$ to both sides gives us $k^2+2k>k+1$.

Comment: You know $k^2 > k+1$ so use it.  $k^2 + 2k + 1 > (k+1)+3k +1> 4k+2 > k+2 = (k+1)+2$.

Comment: I get what you're doing, and perhaps this is just due to the LaTeX barrier, but I think your proof would be made better by clearly spelling out the implications, as the way you've got it set up, you do *need* each transformation to be at least a "$\impliedby$" transformation, which is easy to forget if you aren't being explicit about it.

Comment: induction isn't really needed; $x^2-x-1$ is increasing when $x>\frac12$ and it's $1$ when $x=2$, so $x^2>x+1$ for all real $x\ge2$

Comment: Induction isn't needed as $k\ge 2 > 1$ so $k^2 \ge 2k=k+k>k+1$.  The end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format-wise, I think what you're doing is perfectly fine. I think some more wording would be appropriate though: for instance, the way you have your inductive step written, it almost seems like you're assuming the inequality holds at every step along the way. Usually, I would start at the left-hand side and do manipulations to verify the right-hand side does hold (or the reverse). Still, don't be afraid to use words: being able to explain what you're doing and why is very important in proof-writing!

---

So, on the premise $k^2 > k+1$, you wish you show $(k+1)^2 > k+2$. We see that

$$(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1$$

Invoking the induction hypothesis ($k^2 > k+1$), we see that

$$k^2 + 2k + 1 > k+1 + 2k + 1 = 3k + 2 > k+2$$

(for which the inequality holds since $k$ is assumed positive). Thus, $(k+1)^2 > k+2$ as desired.

Comment: Very well argued, and concise!

Comment: Ok....i'm following you until k + 1 + 2k + 1 how can I get  from k + 2 to k + 1 + 2k + 1?

Comment: $k+1+2k+1 = 3k+2$. Since $k>0$, then $3k > k$. Adding two to each side of that inequality changes it to $3k+2 > k+2$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I appreciate you explaining a bit but can you explain two things: 1) What happens to the $k^2 + 2k + 1$ and 2) how can 3k + 2 be converted to $(k+1)^2$

Answer (score 2):

In an induction step you will have $k^2 > k+1$ and you will need to use is

So We want to show $(k+1)^2 > k+2$ or $k^2 + 2k + 1 > k+1$.

How can we use $k^2 + 1 > k+1$ to do that.

Well $k^2 + 2k + 1 = (k^2)+2k+1 > (k+1)+3k + 1 = 4k+2$.

So if we can somehow prove that $4k + 2 > (k+1) + 1$ we will be done.

......

Alternatively

$k^2 > k+1$ so

$k^2 + 1 > k + 2$

$k^2 + 2k + 1 > k^2  +1 > k+2$

$(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k+ 1 > k^2 + 1 > k+2$.

========

But to complete YOUR proof they way YOU are doing it.

First we can't start with assuming what we want to prove *UNLESS* every step is invertable.  We can't say CONCLUSION implies PREMISE.  But we *can* do CONCLUSION is implied *by* PREMISE or, if it is true, CONCLUSION if and only if PREMISE.

So what you say is:

$(k+1)^2>(k+1)+1\iff$

$k^2+2k+1>(k+1)+1\iff$

$k^2+2k+1>k+2\iff$

$k^2+2k>k+1\iff $

$k(k+2)>k+1$.

Now as $k > 1$ and $k+2 > 0$ then

$k(k+2)>k+1 \Leftarrow$ (is implied *by*; this is not an if and only if)

$k(k+2) > 1*(k+2) > k+1 \Leftarrow$

$k+2 > k+1 \iff$

$2>1$.

.....

If you want to look like a rock star write that backwards.

$2 > 1 \implies$

$k+2 > k+1$ and as $k > 1;k+2>0\implies$

$k(k+2) > 1*(k+2) = k+2>k+1\implies

$k^2 + 2k > k+1\implies$

$k^2 + 2k + 1> k+2\implies$

$(k+1)^2 > (k+1)+1$.

.....

and actually if you did *that* you notice you didn't even use induction.

---

So a non-inductive proof could be:

$1> 0\implies$

$k+1> k\implies$

$k+k > k+1\implies$

$2k > k+1\implies$

$k*k \ge 2k > k+1\implies$

$k^2 > k+1$

Or to pare it down to a single line:

> $k\ge 2>1$ so
>
> $k^2 \ge 2*k = k+k > k+1$.
>
> QED

Comment: Overkill, me thinks!

Answer (score -2):

$$(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1>k+1+2k+1>(k+1)+1.$$